# C++ XOR encrypt/decrypt (xor cipher) doesn't work for me

Tags: c++, encryption, xor

I tried to solve the easy task to train in c++: xor encryption/decryption. But my `gamma()` function doesn't work correctly. It creates result string with strange length, that less or more than original. I don't understand, why. I tried to add `\0` to the end of result string, but it isn't work.

My `gamma()` function is

```
void gamma(char *s1, char *s2, char *res)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++) {
        res[i] = s1[i] ^ s2[i];
}
```

My original strings are
`char source[255] = "1234", key[255] = "avsc", result[255];`

`gamma()` creates a strange string with `length=5`.

Example of output:

`source: 1234dfdfsd
key: avsc234567
source(hex): 31 32 33 34 64 66 64 66 73 64
key(hex): 61 76 73 63 32 33 34 35 36 37
result (hex): 50 44 40 57 56 55 50 53 45 53 4D - length???
try to restore source: 1234dfdfsdM¶
try to restore source in hex: 31 32 33 34 64 66 64 66 73 64 4D 14`

Comment: You cannot use xor on null-terminated strings, you need to keep the length separately.

Comment: And what did you expect to see as output?

Comment: I tried to use C++ strings but i see some errors like `52 18 test.cpp [Error] no match for 'operator^' (operand types are 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')`

@SomeWittyUsername
a string of bytes, which can be interpreted as a sequence of hexadecimal numbers. Their length must match to the length of original text...

Comment: What is "strange output"? Post it

Comment: The length of output is not match to the length of original text. I added an example to my first post.
...
Yes, @n.m. if I added the length of string as a parameter of function, it works. But how i can use C++ style strings?

Comment: `x ^ x == 0` by definition, so null-terminated strings are really not going to be appropriate here. Any time a byte in your data is the same as the corresponding byte in the key, you'll get a zero. You need to work with fixed-sized buffers instead, and pass the byte count to the respective functions so they don't a) terminate at the first zero found or b) continue on beyond the "expected" end of the data.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use `char*` or `std::string` for binary data, as many places it assumed to hold zero terminated string. (for `std::string` it is acctually better, but there are still some issues), so better use `std::vector<unsigned char>` for binary data:

```
typedef std::vector<uin8_t> data;
data gamma( const std::string &str, const std::string &key )
{
    data r( str.length() );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i )
        r[i] = str[i] ^ key[i%key.length()];
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i think, that is very good idea to use vector of chars instead of string types. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to

```
void gamma(char *s1, char *s2, char *res)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s1); i++) {
        res[i] = s1[i] ^ s2[i];
    }
    res[strlen(s1)] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: result of `xor` can be '\0' so it still has issue